# Simple react native app(with react-native-navigation) crash after splash screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to use react-native-navigation as navigation system in my react-native. I've wrote a very simple app for test it, but this app crashes(without giving me any error or info) after the splash screen.

my index.ios.js:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import App from './src/app';
```

my app.ios.js:

```
import {
  Platform
} from 'react-native';
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';

import { registerScreens } from './screens';
registerScreens(); // this is where you register all of your app's screens

// this will start our app
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
  tabs: [{
    label: 'One',
    screen: 'AwesomeProject.Home', // this is a registered name for a screen
    icon: require('../img/one.png'),
    selectedIcon: require('../img/one_selected.png'), // iOS only
    title: 'Screen One'
  }]
});
```

my screens.js

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

import Home from './containers/Home';
import About from './containers/About';

// register all screens of the app (including internal ones)
export function registerScreens() {
  Navigation.registerComponent('AwesomeProject.Home', () => Home);
  Navigation.registerComponent('AwesomeProject.About', () => About);
}
```

my Home.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

my About.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>About!</Text>
    );
  }
}

export default About;
```

You can see a full gist here: https://gist.github.com/inchr/d0184f4ae91abd6036a2fa61725744c9

I've done very test on how loads the tabs in startTabBasedApp() and I've tried to load only a screen too.

Any idea on the reason of the crash/close after the splash screen ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the crash error message to your question

Comment: 2017-04-02 14:54:13.915 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Application AwesomeProject has not been registered. This is either due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the problem was that after I've run: react-native link

I've forgot to edit the AppDelete.m file as explained here: 
https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/wiki/Installation---iOS#installation---ios

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/example/ios/example/AppDelegate.m